Hyperlinks and Image Insert does not work when ShadowDom is applied in ngx-editor
In my application it's required to have ShadowDom in the encapsulation.
In that case the small modal that opens to configure the url it doesn't appear and the same scenario applies for the image insert modal.
ngx-editor version:
v17.5.4
Angular Version
17.3
Link to reproduce
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-editor-floating-menu-custom-pwssuj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Bug opened in ngx-editor: https://github.com/sibiraj-s/ngx-editor/issues/570
It only works when the encapsulation is not ShadowDom
